# I Have a data frame with gender, class and age. I need a result table that gives mean of age by gender and class, difference of mean with observation

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

My data frame is something like this:

```
dat1 <- data.frame(Age = c(21, 20, 17,20,  12, 13, 15,16),
                   Gender = factor(c(2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1), labels = c("Female", "Male")),
                   Class = factor(c(1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 2), labels = c("1st", "2nd")))
```

I need a result table with group mean, group difference, and number of observations each group. My expected result is a table:

```
gender  mean_Age_1st mean_Age_2nd mean_difference  Number_1st Number_2nd
male     20.5         16.5          4               2          2
female    16           14           2               2          2
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is `data.table` option with `dcast`

```
dcast(
  setDT(dat1)[, `:=`(No = .N), .(Gender, Class)],
  Gender ~ ...,
  mean,
  value.var = c("Age", "No")
)[, mean_diff := do.call("-", .SD), .SDcols = patterns("^Age")]
```

which gives

```
   Gender Age_1st Age_2nd No_1st No_2nd mean_diff
1: Female    16.0    14.0      2      2         2
2:   Male    20.5    16.5      2      2         4
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pivot_wider` with multiple `values_from` to achieve what you want:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dat1 %>%
  group_by(Gender, Class) %>%
  summarise(mean_Age = mean(Age),
            Number = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Class, values_from = c(mean_Age, Number)) %>%
  mutate(mean_difference = mean_Age_1st - mean_Age_2nd) %>%
  relocate(mean_difference, .after = mean_Age_2nd) %>%
  arrange(desc(Gender))
```

Comment: Thank. but error showing `n()` must only be used inside dplyr verbs. can you help?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
library(dplyr)
dat1 %>%
  group_by(Gender, Class) %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(Age), number = length(Gender)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = Class, values_from = c(mean, number)) %>%
  mutate(mean_difference = mean_1st - mean_2nd)
```